# Поиск определенного слова без предлога или отрицания с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c#

Возникла необходимость в поиске слова без отрицания или без определенного предыдущего слова. Например, есть предложения, где нужно найти наличие только слова "пружинная" без "не":

- "... слова ... не пружинная ... слова ... пружинная ..." `true`
- "... слова ... не пружинная и пружинная ..." `true`
- "... слова ... пружинная, не пружинная ..." `true`
- "... слова ... пружинная ..." `true`
- "... слова ... не пружинная ..." `false`

Не могу подобрать регулярное выражение, для метода:

```
private static bool IsMatch(string regExp, string s)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regex.IsMatch(s);
}
```

Спасибо за любую помощь или направление, куда копать. Без регулярного могу решить эту задачу, но интуитивно чувствую, что и с регулярным выражением есть решение))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется Negative Lookbehind, почитать можно здесь https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Поиграться можно здесь https://regex101.com/r/H9bUTD/1

Само выражение, например, для приведенного фрагмента, такое:

```
(?<!не\s)пружинная
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!Negative Lookbehind
да, я примерно так и думал, что подобное нужно применять

Answer (score 0):

Немного переделал под свои нужды для 3 и 6 вариантов, когда "НЕ" входит в состав другого или текущего слова.

Вот так вышло:

```
@"(?<!\bне\s)\bпружинная)"
```

Это работает для строк, где должно быть `true`:

1. "... пружинная, "
2. "... пружинная НЕ"
3. "... односторонНЕ пружинная, "

И для строк, где должно быть `false`:

4. "НЕ пружинная, "
5. "... НЕ пружинная, "
6. "... НЕпружинная, "

Надеюсь, что составил данное регулярное выражение корректно.